# Wrong number of parameters to printf leads to strange results

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   int i=10,j=20;
   printf("%d%d%d",i,j);
   printf("%d",i,j); 
   return 0;
}
```

Using the Turbo C compiler, the output is like:

```
10 10 garbageValue

20
```

Can someone explain why this is?

Comment: Undefined behavior. There is no use thinking about what it may have done behind the scenes due to two reasons: you will not use this code and every compiler is different.

Answer (score 2):

The first call to `printf()` has one too many format specifiers, resulting in undefined behaviour. In this case a garbage value is printed.

Comment: See the title to his question -- he clearly knows this already. The second one has the wrong number of arguments as well, by the way.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill, the title of the question has changed since I posted this. As for the second, I noticed there are the incorrect number of arguments however I cannot explain why it prints `20` and not `10`. Reading the C specification it indicates that `10` should be printed (the `i` processed and the `j` ignored).

Comment: Yeah, but I think the original still expresses the notion.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill, I can't see how the OP already knows that this causes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("%d%d%d",i,j); =>
```

you are telling printf to print three integer, but you provide just three, so printf prints some garbage from the stack.
the other:

```
printf("%d",i,j);
```

is supposed to take just one integer, but you are passing two.
The C language does not guard against such errors, and what's happen is completely undefined, so to explain how you see *exactly* these outputs is difficult unless you know your compiler internal, and not so useful since that code is wrong and expected to fail.

Comment: The second `printf` call is not undefined in the C standard. See C99 7.19.6.1:2. The OP's compiler is not standard-compliant.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior is *undefined*, meaning the language spec doesn't say what happens in this case. It depends entirely on the implementation of the compiler and on your system architecture. Explaining undefined behavior can be occasionally entertaining, often maddening, and pretty much always useless -- so don't worry about it!

Answer (score 1):

You've got your format specifiers all mixed up, and I don't think the code you posted is your actual code.  On my Visual Studio compiler, I see this:

```
1020010
```

Each `%d` denotes a place where `printf` should insert one of your integer values.

```
printf("%d%d%d",i,j);
```

You told `printf` to expect three, but you only gave it two.  It's possible Turbo C is doing something different with the arguments under the hood, but you still need to match your format specifiers to your arguments:

```
printf("%d%d",i,j);
```

Comment: Of course Turbo C does something different  -- this is undefined behavior, and every compiler is implemented differently.